# many webview inside flipview winrt

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have flipview and inside flipview there is a webview. But I have a problem. If I binding too many items on this flipview my flipview get crashed. This is the xaml from my flipview

```
  <FlipView Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                      x:Name="BookPageContentFlipView" Tapped="OnBookPageContentFlipViewTapped"
                      DoubleTapped="OnBookPageContentFlipViewDoubleTapped"
                      ItemsSource={Binding BookPages} SelectionChanged="BookPageContentFlipViewSelectionChanged">
                <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Webview  Source={Binding Book}/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

It just a sample but actually I load from local string. So how do I can bind many items to this flipview?

Comment: You shouldn't really do this. Each Webview is essentially an almost-whole web browser, therefore not something to use lightly with several instances.

Comment: I have an idea about using just 3 webview inside flipview but I am confusing how to implement it. Can I binding all to flipview and just showing 3. Actually I just need previous page, current page, and next page. the problem is when changing page

Comment: What are you trying to build? Do you need live `WebView`s? Managing just a few in a `FlipView` will never be very seamless as the flipping occurs, especially if it's flipped quickly.

Comment: You might need to offscreen a single `WebView`, and render its content to a bitmap when it finishes loading. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.capturepreviewtostreamasync.aspx

Comment: I want to create a book. every page is formatted in web so I need to show it inside webview. and one book usually contain > 100 pages. and I need seamlessly transition in tablet so when they scrolling they can use animation transition like in flipview